# Scala generic type parameters issues

Tags: scala, generics

I'm relatively new to Scala and I'm having issues with generic type parameters. I'm implementing command pattern for certain operations and I have a base class like this:

```
abstract class Command[A, B <: BaseModel, T[X] <: CommandResponseWrapper[X] forSome { type X }](repository: BaseRepository[A, B], entity: B) {

  @throws(classOf[Exception])
  def execute: Future[T[X] forSome { type X }]
}
```

Now, take this concrete command as a sample of the issues I'm having:

```
case class AgentExecutionListCommand(repository: AgentExecutionRepository[Int, AgentExecution], entity: AgentExecution)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Command[Int, AgentExecution, AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[AgentExecution]]](repository, entity){
  override def execute: Future[AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[AgentExecution]]] = {
    repository.getAllMastersForAgent(entity.agentId).map(ae => AgentExecutionListResponse(ae))
  }

  override def toString: String = "Command is: AgentExecutionListCommand"
}

case class AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[AgentExecution]](response: Seq[AgentExecution]) extends CommandResponseWrapper
```

The method getAllMastersForAgent in the repository, returns a Future[Seq[AgentExecution]], but the compiler shows an error in this line:

```
repository.getAllMastersForAgent(entity.agentId).map(ae => AgentExecutionListResponse(ae))
```

**The error is: Expression of type AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq] doesn't conform to expected type S_**

What does that mean?

Another error is:

```
Error:(11, 189) org.jc.dpwmanager.commands.AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[org.jc.dpwmanager.models.AgentExecution]] takes no type parameters, expected: one
case class AgentExecutionListCommand(repository: AgentExecutionRepository[Int, AgentExecution], entity: AgentExecution)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Command[Int, AgentExecution, AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq]](repository, entity){
```

Why does it say that it takes no type parameters and then again, expects one. I don't get it. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 case class AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[AgentExecution]](response: Seq[AgentExecution]) extends CommandResponseWrapper
```

The `[...]` thingy should be after `CommandResponseWrapper` not after the class name

```
  case class AgentExecutionListResponse(
    response: Seq[AgentExecution]
  ) extends CommandResponseWrapper[Seq[AgentExecution]]
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second error:

`T[X] <: CommandResponseWrapper[X] forSome { type X }` means you told the compiler `T` has to be a type constructor with a single parameter (that's why you can write `T[X]` in `execute`'s signature), but `AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[AgentExecution]]` doesn't take parameters (you can't write `AgentExecutionListResponse[Seq[AgentExecution]][SomeType]`). So you can't use it as `T`. Just as if you try to call `foo()` where `foo` has a parameter.

Also, I think that the scope of `X` in `forSome` is just `CommandResponseWrapper[X] forSome { type X }`, so it's the same as `T[X] <: CommandResponseWrapper[_]`. So naming `X` in `T[X]` is confusing.

Given the signature you expect for `AgentExecutionListCommand#execute`, the fix might be just

```
abstract class Command[A, B <: BaseModel, T <: CommandResponseWrapper[_]](repository: BaseRepository[A, B], entity: B) {

  @throws(classOf[Exception])
  def execute: Future[T]
}
```

but it really depends on what you want.

For the first, it isn't clear where `S_` comes from: perhaps from `getAllMastersForAgent`'s signature? In that case it would be necessary for the answer. But the second is a more fundamental issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Alexey Romanov. What I'm trying to write here is that  AgentExecutionListCommand#execute must return a subtype of CommandResponseWrapper, which also has some nested type (CommandResponseWrapper[Can be of any Type]).

Comment: @JorgeCespedes This seems to be exactly what I suggest in the "the fix might be just" paragraph. Try it and see if it works out.

Comment: (though I didn't notice another problem, the one Dima points out)